# Prove, using eigenvalues/eigenvectors, that if $AB = BA$ for any $B$, then $A = cI$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The property $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}, c \in \mathbb{K}: (\forall B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}: AB = BA) \implies A=cI$ is well-known and not particularly complex. Proofs of the property exist in other questions, including  a [question asked by myself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598925/proving-forall-b-in-mathbbkn-times-n-ab-ba-iff-a-ci-n) two months ago. Most proofs of this property are done algebraically. However, I was now requested to provide a proof using theory acquired from the study of characteristic polynomials, eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Naturally, when one thinks of $cI$ in terms of eigenvalues/eigenvectors, one thinks of the matrix representation of a mapping with $n$ eigenvalues $c, \ldots, c$, where the eigenvectors are the standard basis $\mathcal{C} = \{(1, 0, \ldots, 0), (0, 1, \ldots, 0), \ldots, (0, 0, \ldots, 1 \}$. In other words, one knows $A$ is the matrix representation of a linear operator $T \in \text{Hom}(V, V)$ such that $Tw_1 = cw_1, \ldots, Tw_n = cw_n$ for every $w_i \in \mathcal{C}$.

However, the relationship between this "eigen-interpretation" of $cI$ and its commutability with every $B \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ (or every $F \in \text{Hom}(V,V)$) escapes me. I would very much appreciate hints, corrections if I'm paying attention to the wrong aspects of the matter, or simply the required proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a good start would be something like: Say $Av = cv.$ Then $A(Bv) = (AB)v = (BA)v = c(Bv).$ This means that for any eigen-pair $(c,v)$ of $A$, one also gets $(c, Bv)$ is an eigen-pair of $A.$ This  then produces a chain of such pairs: $(c,Bv)\implies (c,B^2v)\implies \ldots .$

Comment: The property is not well stated. As you write it, $c$ is universally quantified. It should read something like "$\forall B(AB=BA)\implies \exists c(A=cI)$.

Comment: Is the field $\mathbb{K}$ meant to be the complex numbers? I ask this because in general $A$ may not have eigenvalues/eigenvectors and so you can't expect to get a proof that starts off assuming that it does. The whole question seems to me to be misguided: the standard proof is so trivial that anything else is just threshing about.

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ is a $\lambda$-eigenvector of $A$ then

$$ A(Bv) = BA v = B\lambda v = \lambda Bv.$$

so $Bv$ is an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue as long as $Bv \neq 0$.

Since this holds for any $B$ such that $Bv \neq 0$  it means that if $A$ has a single eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then all non-zero vectors are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Therefore showing that

$$ A = \lambda I_n.$$

You would still have to prove that $A$ has at least one eigenvector to conclude.

Comment: As eigenvectors are by definition non-zero your first sentence is false.

Comment: @ancientmathematician You mean that $B$ could map the eigenvector to $0$, right ?

Comment: Indeed. $0$-eigenvectors always cause special cases.